# Serverless Nested Stack - An error occurred: LogStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I use serverless for deploying my application (NodeJS) to AWS. Until yesterday i had totaly 55 endpoints & 4 Lambda functions it was working fine. Now I have 64 endpoints & 5 lambda functions I got below error

```
**The Cloud Formation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 232, is greater than maximum allowed, 200**
```

So i tried serverless-nested-stack plugin now I get below errors

```
**An error occurred: APIStack - Template format error: Number of resources, 221, is greater than maximum allowed, 200**

**An error occurred: LogStack - Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:943203963451:stack/premierxnew-dev-LogStack-1GT5J43EL92T9/de4913a0-db05-11e7-909b-50a68ae71462 was not successfully c
reated: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AppOtherLogGroup, AppFaqLogGroup, AppUserLogGroup, AppOrderLogGroup, AppEventLogGroup]. .**
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've reached a hard limit of CloudFormation template. The doc says you should split your resources between multiple nested stacks to workaround this limit. I assume you use the `serverless deploy` command which, as the doc tells:

> "[...] translates all syntax in serverless.yml to a **single** AWS
>   CloudFormation template".

But there is hope, there's actually a GitHub issue on this subject: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2995.

And users in the thread are suggesting the use of this plugin: https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks.

> The goal of this plugin is to split some resources off in to nested
>   stacks to work around the 200 CloudFormation resource limit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried with that too and i got below error

An error occurred: APINestedStack - Template format error: Outputs count 62 is greater than max allowed 60.

Comment: You are clearly pushing the limits of the Serverless and CloudFormation, which is good. I think you should voice your concern in the issue opened on the serverless repository. Also, you could contact AWS support to ask if these limits are "hard" or "soft". In the latter case AWS could increase the limit for your account. I'll leave my answer here as it could help others.

Comment: Thanks mate. Have requested for limit increase to aws support regarding the same. Lets see how it goes